# Software recommendation: wiki with direct image pasting

Tags: software-recommendation, markdown

I create a lot of "howto" documents that need to include images of configuration dialogs -- often with a bit of background for context.  The easiest way I've found to *collect* the images is with "screenshot rectangle", which clipboards the selection area.

The obvious workflow is to paste the clipboard image directly into my document.

I'd much rather be creating wiki pages than .docx files.

Is there any Linux markdown editor (or wiki service) that supports direct image pasting?  Extra points for WYSIWYG editing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your exact use case but you may be satisfied with [Zim](http://zim-wiki.org/) editor.

I admit that you don't edit in markdown but in an internal wiki markup (which is quite similar to markdown, ex: bold is the same) that is converted to rich text on the fly. (Or you can use standard WYSIWYG document shortcuts, like Ctrl+b for bold.)

Zim grabs well clipboard images, stores them to a folder, produces pure .txt files, that can be exported to markdown, html or whatever you want.

Plus, in the future you may find a [full markdown support](https://github.com/zim-desktop-wiki/zim-desktop-wiki/issues/26).

If pure markdown is crucial right now, I may point you to Gitlab (either free g or self-hosted). Every Gitlab repository can have its own wiki space that is able to grab images from clipboard.

Comment: Good answer.  I'm actually going to be using the GitHub-issue solution I've posted below (we develop on Github), but your solution more precisely answers my question.

Answer (score 0):

Not a generic wiki solution, but I did find [a way to do it](https://ardalis.com/add-images-easily-to-github) relatively easily on GitHub.

Basically, you create an issue on Github.  You can paste a clipboard image directly into the issue's text field -- it auto-uploads the image, and converts it to a markdown link.  The markdown link is persistent; it can then be copied directly into the wiki page.